# PHP site doesn't validate with W3C, due to PHPSESSID

Tags: php, validation

My site isn't validating due to PHPSESSID being seen in the source code, however, this wasn't happening just a few days ago and I've not done anything to cause this, as far as I am aware.  My host also denies any knowledge of changing anything.

The PHPSESSID isn't visible when I view the source of the pages myself, so it seems to be something to do with the interaction between my site and the validator.  Any ideas how I can resolve it, I have trawled the internet and tried various settings on the server but to no avail.

I know that PHPSESSID is used when cookies are blocked, has the validator changed somehow?

I realise there are other validation issues on there as well but I know how to fix those and will be doing so over the coming days.

Thanks for any advice.

The site is http://www.fantasy-f1-league.com/info.php (that's a PHP info page, the site is without the file name at the end)

Comment: Don't leave your phpinfo() page publicly accessible!

Comment: Do people actually put critically private stuff in their PHP config?  Really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `session.use_trans_sid` option, which tells PHP to persist the session ID via non-cookie means. That means PHP will be parseing your page, looking for ANY links and forms, and adding the session ID as a query parameter and/or hidden form field.

trans_sid is a nasty security risk if you're doing anything "important",b ecause it DOES transmit the session ID around in URLs, means it's utterly trivial to hijack someone's session, and the session ID will also leak out to other sites in HTTP REFERERS and whatnot.

Comment: So if I get rid of that will people who block cookies still be able to use the site?  Why has it suddenly caused this issue as it was validating a few days ago? Thanks.

Comment: If your site depends on sessions, then no. No cookies, no trans sid = no sessions. Check who changed the server config - either it's through the main php.ini, or a .htaccess/httpd.conf override.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked my host to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It does not validate because in the links & should be replaced with `&amp;`.

Also ..

- who the hell uses HTML4.01 transitional in this day an age ?!
- move your JS code to an external file(s), which you include before `</body>`
- `LANGUAGE="JavaScript"` has not place in `<script>`
- class names should describe **what** the tag contains , and not where it is and how it looks like
- `<center>` tag is deprecated

Comment: Apparently at least one person still uses HTML4.  :)  Not like it hurts the web; it just means he can't play with most of the new hotness.

Comment: @davidjwest: It's there when i go to the site.  The first visit, if the client doesn't present a cookie, the server rewrites links to include the session ID.

Comment: @davidjwest , well that was what is saw in validations results, because it was validating for me

Comment: @cHao I also still use HTML4. Looking forward to HTML5, but it's not done yet, and support spotty in the browsers. Looking forward to CSS3 even more.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't realised so few sites used it, what's best, HTML 5?  http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/HTML-4.01-Transitional-DTD  300k sites use it give or take.

Comment: @JMack , don't hold your breath for CSS3. The support and the spec is simply coming. And it is actually causing additional problems, because people keep on using the experimental vendor prefixes.

Comment: @tereško To add to the mess, not only do vendors have their own prefixes, but they have started to adopt prefixes from OTHER vendors as well.

Comment: @tereško - thanks, didn't realise that, sorry if I was a bit abrupt - but it isn't in MY source, so not sure how I can fix it, I am aware of the "&amp;" solution, but I can't use that in this instance.  I am also aware of the other fixes you've listed.

Comment: @davidjwest , if it is not your source, just leave them there. There is no sane way for you to change it without access to the code which generated it. If your boss demands, that you create a valid site, then you should in return demand access to the original code. Its the old `garbage in , garbage out` principle.